# Adding an error message when detecting elements of an array that are out of order

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

I have to create code that merges two arrays together with all elements in order, lowest to highest. If an out of order element is found, I'm supposed print the message “ERROR: Array not in correct order”. I have all the code working, except I don't know where or how I can add this error message.

An example error output:

Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit

4
5
7
2
-1

Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit
3
3
3
3
3
3
0

First Array: 
4 5 7 2

Second Array: 
3 3 3 3 3 3

ERROR: Array not in correct order

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int one[]= new int[10000];  
    int two[]= new int[10000];  
    int lengthShort=0;          
    int lengthLong=0;           
    int a =0;                   
    int b =0;
    System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit");
    for(int i=0; i<one.length; i++){

        one[i] = scan.nextInt();
        a++;
        if(one[i]<=0){
            one[i]=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    int length1 = a-1;

    System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit");
    for(int i=0; i<two.length; i++){

        two[i] = scan.nextInt();
        b++;
        if(two[i]<=0){
            two[i]=0;
            break;
        } 

    }


    int lengthTwo = b-1;


    int mergeOne[] = new int[length1];  
    for (int i = 0; i<mergeOne.length; i++){
        mergeOne[i]=one[i];
    }
    int mergeTwo[] = new int[lengthTwo];   
    for (int i = 0; i<mergeTwo.length; i++){
        mergeTwo[i]=two[i];
    }


    System.out.println("First Array:");

    for(int i=0; i<mergeOne.length; i++){
    System.out.print(mergeOne[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nSecond Array:");

    for(int i=0; i<mergeTwo.length; i++){
    System.out.print(mergeTwo[i] + " ");
    }


    if(mergeOne.length<=mergeTwo.length){
        lengthLong = mergeTwo.length;
        lengthShort = mergeOne.length;
    }

    else if(mergeOne.length>=mergeTwo.length){
        lengthShort = mergeTwo.length;
        lengthLong = mergeOne.length;
    }

    int merged[] = new int[length1 + lengthTwo];


    for(int i = 0; i<lengthShort; i++){
        if(i==0){
            if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
                merged[i] = mergeOne[i];
                merged[i+1] = mergeTwo[i];
            }
            else if(mergeTwo[i]<=mergeOne[i]){
                merged[i] = mergeTwo[i];
                merged[i+1]= mergeOne[i];
            }
        }
        else if(i>0){
            if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
                merged[i+i] = mergeOne[i];
                merged[i+i+1] = mergeTwo[i];
            }
            else if(mergeTwo[i]<=mergeOne[i]){
                merged[i+i] = mergeTwo[i];
                merged[i+i+1]= mergeOne[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if(mergeOne.length<mergeTwo.length){
        for(int k=lengthShort; k<lengthLong; k++){
            merged[k]=mergeTwo[k];
        }
    }
    if(mergeOne.length>mergeTwo.length){
            for(int k=lengthShort; k<lengthLong; k++){
                merged[k]=mergeOne[k];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<merged.length; i++){
        if((i+1)==merged.length)       
            break;
        if(merged[i]>merged[i+1]){
            int temp = merged[i+1];
            merged[i+1]=merged[i];
            merged[i]= temp;

        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nMerged Array: ");

    for(int i = 0; i<merged.length; i++){
    System.out.print(merged[i] + " ");
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: What do u mean by "Array not in correct order" ? Do you mean array size ?

Comment: are you looking for a java or javascript solution ?

Comment: Array not in correct order: If the number after your previous entry is less than the previous entry, then it's not in the correct order.

Comment: Javascript would be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want processing to stop when the error is found, then throw an exception.   Catch that exception at the root-most part of the program (the main routine or whatever you called it) and display the value of the exception.

If you don't want processing to stop -- that is you want to keep processing and looking for other problems -- then you have to display the error in the code doing the processing.

Is this a command line program?  If so, then a System.out.println will output whatever string value you want to the console.

Comment: All it does is just say there was an error. It should still print the two arrays, just not the merged one.

Comment: I was thinking of using a flag variable of some sort. Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you could implement a isSorted() method which would return a boolean like :

```js
var isSorted = a => {
  var result = true;
  a.forEach((x,i,arr) => {
    if (i < arr.length && arr[i+1] < x) result = false;
  })
  return result;
}
console.log(isSorted([1,2,3,6,8,12]));
console.log(isSorted([1,2,3,-6,8,12]));
```